# How to retrieve the Twitch API bearer token

Tags: rest, authorization, twitch-api

I'm not sure how to summarize this problem other than either some of the most passive aggressive or clueless docs I have ever scoured (and I've seen and written my fair share!) especially from a subsidiary of an ostensibly fortune 5 company

In any case: as an aspiring Twitch API user, I want to perform general server side requests of Twitch API resources (user/channel resources etc) and I need to provide a Bearer Token in an  `Authorization` header.

Ok, easy enough you think? Oh you sweet summer child, the Twitch docs have incredibly detailed sections on the [four different authorization flows](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/authentication#getting-tokens) you can venture to try to get this mysteriously hard to retrieve token (that is literally like 1 step in any other API)

Each of those flows have a fairly good step by step enumeration and how you need to first make sure you have a twitch application registered and the app's Client-Id and client Secret handy.

After that step, the closest you get is downloading the Twitch CLI, invoking the `twitch token` command and then passing in your Client-Id and client secret to get an expiring access token that can be passed in as the bearer, but what if:

1. the twitch CLI won't install on my machine?
2. I don't want to install the twitch CLI?
3. I need to generate a new access token programmatically (which is like, the whole point of an API???) without bash scripting a CLI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tl;dr, this took me way too much time, so I'm sharing with you because it's ridiculous this took so long:

`POST https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials`

**Headers**
`"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`

Form body: (choose 'form' option in Insomnia or Postman)

```
client_id <your app's client id>
client_secret <your app's client secret>
redirect_uri <your app's redirect uri (localhost is fine!)>
code <your app's client secret (yes, again)
```

Posting that worked for me, and returned this 200 OK and JSON response:

```
{
  "access_token": "<relevant access token>",
  "expires_in": 5046783,
  "token_type": "bearer"
}
```

Although the Twitch docs liberally share plenty of other endpoints, for some reason I can only speculate on, they do not share explicitly and clearly share the endpoint for retrieving the endpoint for generating Twitch API bearer tokens.

Fortunately, they *do* share their [Twitch CLI's code on Github](https://github.com/twitchdev/twitch-cli/tree/80f8da3e57cf4945b19388bf571c9fa36b82793c/internal/login) which we can investigate further.

Within this codebase, we can see several urls assigned to variables and called in a nested `if` statement in the `cmd` go file.

After chasing around the repo and some smooth brain keyboard bashing, I got the result I was looking for.

I hope you find this useful and please don't write docs like this at your company!

Comment: Works as advertised. Amazed they use CLI examples instead of providing what the CLI does in the documentation. Thank you.